# Can I install a trip lever drain on a new tub that doesn’t currently use one?

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

I have a brand new tub. How can I tell if I can install a trip style drain? Right now we are just using a plug and the faceplate doesn’t have a lever. I was reading online that these drains aren’t always compatible.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind cutting into the floor and wall to replace the drain system in place now, you sure can install any kind you like. Some might even have the proper diameter vent tube and you could drop the drain system in without much fuss. It all depends on what you want to tackle.

Comment: I'll take that as a "there's not an easy way to do it". :)

Comment: There is, if your drain assembly you have, will take a drop-in lever stopper.